# Qt and LNK1104 cannot open file

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to accomplish the "hello world" tutorial with Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 500 MB) (Info).
However when I press Run the project I have an LNK1104: cannot open file 'debug/Hello.exe' error. However I see that this file is created under project folder "F:\QT\Hello\build-Hello-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug". Thank you in advance

Main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    QPushButton button;
    button.setText("Hello world !");
    button.setToolTip("heheheheheheheh");
    button.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Hello.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Hello

QT = core gui
QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Comment: Is Hello.exe running in the background?  Look at your Processes list in your task manager.

Comment: Nope, this is happening also after computer restart. I check Process list and nothing is there. It worth noticing that if I create new project (hello) first time it runs Ok but if i modify it little it throw the above error.

Answer (score 10):

Most likely cause for the problem: `.exe` file of your program is still running. Check with Task Manager.End this process from task manager and again try to built it.It will definitely run.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Works perfect using Qt Quick Controls application output was: LNK1104 /debug/"name".exe could not be opened.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue to fix it I went to project right above the run (play button) 
clicked on build and switched to debug. Not sure why but it worked for me.
Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by file permission or linking issues.

Additionally, Microsoft Development Network has an extensive list of possible causes (and solutions) for your problem:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx